# Gradle conflict between two tasks

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm writing few tasks in gradle and I have a strange error.

```
task buildProduction() {
    description 'Build the production version of the app (creates the yaml file)'
    copyAndReplaceYaml("Production")
}

task buildStaging() {
    description 'Build the staging version of the app (creates the yaml file)'
    copyAndReplaceYaml("Staging")
}
```

When I run buildStaging, it works fine, but when I run buildProduction, it's like I'm running buildStaging.

If I switch the place of the methods in the file `buildProduction` works and not `buildStaging`.

Any idea why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're executing the copy as part as the task *configuration*, which is executed always, whatever the command is, and before the tasks are executed. You need to change the code of the two tasks to

```
task buildStaging {
    description 'Build the staging version of the app (creates the yaml file)'
}
buildStaging << {
    copyAndReplaceYaml("Staging")
}
```

or

```
task buildStaging {
    description 'Build the staging version of the app (creates the yaml file)'
    doLast {
        copyAndReplaceYaml("Staging")
    }
}
```